# apt-get install -y nginx with newer version

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, apt-get

In Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  nginx
```

I think I got a very old version of nginx this way. How can I install a newer version, like 1.15.7?
Can I do something like:

```
FROM node:8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  curl \
  # Where to download the nginx source? Pass the download path below
  && curl -sL \
  && apt-get install -y nginx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node:8 use debian stretch,so
1. Open /etc/apt/sources.list in a text editor and add the following line to the bottom:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx
```

2. Import the repository’s package signing key and add it to apt:

```
sudo wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
```

3. Install nginx

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a package using `apt-get` with a specific version, you simply could:

> Install Version

```
sudo apt-get install <package name>=<version>
```

> Nginx

```
sudo apt-get install nginx=1.5.*
```

> Re (Comment) Option 1: Installing Nginx from its Mainline Repository:

**You’ll need to install the key in order for Ubuntu to trust packages from that repository.**

```
cd /tmp/ && wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
```

**After adding the key, run the commands below to install Nginx’s Mainline repository or branch on Ubuntu.**

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ '$(lsb_release -cs)' nginx' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Nginx.list"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

> Re (Comment) Option 2: Installing Nginx From Its Stable Repository:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/stable/ubuntu/ '$(lsb_release -cs)' nginx' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Nginx.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: It says Version '1.15.*' for 'nginx' was not found. It only works with `nginx=1.10.3-1+deb9u2` which is old, broken version.